# How to Check Facebook user is logged in or not in Javascript

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Check Facebook user is logged in or not in Javascript wihtout Appid
I have the Code to check the wheather the user is loggedin or not using javscript
These all need Appid. Is their any other way to Find that without a Appid?

Comment: That's not possible,

Answer (score 2):

> The method `FB.init()` is used to initialize and setup the SDK.
>   [...]
>   All other SDK methods must be called after this one, because they won't exist until you do.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init

Therefore, you can't use `FB.getLoginStatus()` (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus) until you've initialized with `FB.init()` which requires an App ID.